# Simplifying a double summation related to a Ramanujan-type pi formula $1/\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, pi

I came across an integer sequence for a Ramanujan-type formula for $1/\pi$, namely,
$$a(n)=\color{brown}{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}^4 = 1, 4, 36, 424, 5716, 83568, 1289352,\dots$$

where $a(0)=1$. **Q:** Is there any way to simplify the brown part, maybe reduce the number of binomials, or even reduce $a(n)$ to a single-summation?

**P.S.** I tried to investigate the properties of the brown part, and it seems to be related to a *number triangle* given by [A046521](https://oeis.org/A046521), but I can't get it to yield the numbers above.

Comment: Using some heuristics, I found the asymptotic formula $$
a(n) \sim 5 \cdot \frac{{20^n }}{{(2\pi n)^{3/2} }}
$$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: @Gary You may be interested to know this sequence is a for a level-$10$ Ramanujan-type pi formula, so the presence of $5$ and $20^n$ in the asymptotics is a nice fact.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII can you please link some references for these Ramanujan-type pi formulas? I am interested in learning about them

Comment: @Zima The Wikipedia article [Ramanujan-Sato series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) should be a good start. Or you can check out my MO posts for [level 6](https://mathoverflow.net/q/448777/12905), for [level 10](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905), and [level 12](https://mathoverflow.net/q/448834/12905).